# Ruby. Two threads instead of one

Tags: ruby, multithreading

When I run a Ruby program the interpreter creates two threads instead of one.

Here's the example program:

```
# example.rb

sleep 60
```

And [that](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20481401/threads.png) is the work result of the following command:

`watch -ctn1 'ps -T -eo cmd,pid,nlwp,lwp | grep "ruby example.rb" | grep -v "grep"'`

Why does Ruby behave such a way?

Thanks.

Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1;

Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 3):

sleep() function executes in a separate thread. Ruby always starts two thread during initialization threads.

You can get more information by using strace and gdb:

```
$ strace -f ruby -e "sleep 1" 2>&1 | less
$ strace -f ruby -e "puts '12'" 2>&1 | less

$ gdb ruby
(gdb) set args -e 'puts "12"'
(gdb) break start_thread
Function "start_thread" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (start_thread) pending.
(gdb) run 
Starting program: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby -e 'puts "12"'
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0xb7b47b70 (LWP 27630)]
[Switching to Thread 0xb7b47b70 (LWP 27630)]

Breakpoint 1, 0xb7dd68b6 in start_thread () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 2 (Thread 0xb7b47b70 (LWP 27630)):
#0  0xb7dd68b6 in start_thread () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0
#1  0xb7cdea4e in clone () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0xb7c0f6c0 (LWP 27627)):
#0  0xb7fe2430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7ddb015 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0
#2  0xb7f711f1 in native_cond_wait () at thread_pthread.c:127
#3  rb_thread_create_timer_thread () at thread_pthread.c:836
#4  0xb7e669b5 in rb_call_inits () at inits.c:57
#5  0xb7e48d1d in ruby_init () at eval.c:60
#6  0x080487de in main (argc=3, argv=0xbffff834) at main.c:34
```